# parsing text files using boost regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, boost, expression

I'm trying to parse a textfile in C++ using the `boost::regex` library.

I'm trying to parse this line into my program:
1_3,1,3,0

- 1_3 needs to become the name in string
- 1 needs to become an X-coordinate in char
- 3 needs to become an Y-coordinate in char
- 0,needs to become a cost for a function, also a char

Do you guys know what match to write?

I tried this one but it didn't work:

```
boost::regex rgex("^([0-9]),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+).*");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the acceptable characters for each part of the line?

Comment: before the first comma it needs to become a string so 0-9,a-z,A-Z and punctuation marks are allowed. for the next three only digits are allowed. but i need to check on multiple digits.

This could be a line: "name,100,200,3000"

Comment: In your example the first group has an underscore `_`. Is the example not valid?

Comment: Isn't it `^([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd not do this using regexes, which leaves you having to the all the type conversions.

I'd parse directly into a `vector<>` of structs

```
struct record {
    std::string name;
    char x, y, cost;
};
```

With Boost Spirit, like

```
std::vector<record> data;
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l,
    (qi::lexeme[+~qi::char_(',')] >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ',' >> qi::int_) % qi::eol,
    qi::blank,
    data);

if (ok)
{
    std::cout << "Parsed success: " << data.size() << " records\n";
    for(auto& r : data)
        std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Note that this approach accepts and ignores extra whitespace (`qi::blank`).

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0ff0417668e031a)** which prints:

```
Parsed success: 11 records
1_3 1   3   0
16_92   16  92  76
8_31    8   31  13
3_45    3   45  46
12_67   12  67  66
17_27   17  27  2
7_72    7   72  74
0_36    0   36  25
18_30   18  30  50
6_35    6   35  19
16_5    16  5   50
```

---

#### Full Code

for reference

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct record {
    std::string name;
    char x, y, cost;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const record& r) {
        return os << r.name << "\t" << int(r.x) << "\t" << int(r.y) << "\t" << int(r.cost);
    }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(record, (std::string, name)(char, x)(char, y)(char, cost))

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss(
            "1_3,1,3,0\n"
            "16_92,16,92,76\n"
            "8_31,8,31,13\n"
            "3_45,3,45,46\n"
            "12_67,12,67,66\n"
            "17_27,17,27,2\n"
            "7_72,7,72,74\n"
            "0_36,0,36,25\n"
            "18_30,18,30,50\n"
            "6_35,6,35,19\n"
            "16_5,16,5,50"
        );

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(iss >> std::noskipws), l;

    std::vector<record> data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l,
        (qi::lexeme[+~qi::char_(',')]
         >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ',' >> qi::int_
        ) % qi::eol,
        qi::blank,
        data);

    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed success: " << data.size() << " records\n";
        for(auto& r : data)
            std::cout << r << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
    {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, they managed to merge the compilation times of templates, the general verbosity of C++ and the unreadability of regexes to do the equivalent of `scanf("%[^','],%d,%d,%d",... `, I'm seriously impressed. =)

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'm surprised you could report on the compilation times so soon (~5 minutes) after me posting the answer. Congrats on your HPC!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all the acceptable characters, the simplest way to parse the line is to separate by the commas.

`"^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),(.+)$"`

`[^,]` means any non-comma character. `[^,]+` means 1 or more non-comma character.